# Godot immediately crashes upon opening a 3D scene

Tags: opengl, vulkan, godot, godot4

All of this started when I updated my Intel UHD Graphics driver. After editing in a 3D scene for a while, Godot will immediately crash on me with error of

`ERROR: Vulkan: Cannot submit graphics queue. Error code: VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST`

in the console logs. When it crashes sometimes it would say it 3 times only, or keep saying it until I close it.

After updating my graphics driver, my Godot (was in v4.1.2) kept crashing with said error with a blend file warning & a OpenGL (in v3.0) invalid cache pipeline warning when opening project. So I:

1. Updated my Godot to v4.2 and changed my project version to that

   - Didn't work, same thing happened
2. Made my project to not use OpenGL and use Vulkan only, and also enabled one of the text rendering stuff disabled by default cuz' why not.

   - Made my problem worse, now crashing when I load a 3D scene, even if it was in a brand new project
3. Roll Backed my driver update to my previous one where my Godot was fine

   - Nothing even happened
4. Disabled blend file import

   - Didn't expect any changes to this and did exactly what I expected, nothing.

I suppose there's no more warnings now, just error upon even 3 seconds into editing a 3D scene.

Note that starting a new project will cause the same issue just with the blend file warning, since it immediately starts rendering in 3D.

Comment: Did you try with a new project? If it works, you could compare the project files and try to discard if there is any particular feature that causes it. You could also try taking out the .godot folder so Godot has to regenerate it.

Comment: @Theraot opening a new project will cause the same issue, i have no idea why. (with the blend file warning at the start since i didnt disable it, but thats not the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind it just seemed to fixed it itself after installing an update for my driver from Lenovo via device manager (my laptop is a Lenovo) instead of installing an update directly from Intel.

Also the engine build configuration was restored back to default so there's that.